# Batteries for Drones

Tags: batteries, circuit-design, lithium, lithium-polymer

I am making a drone for geological applications and for that we require a flight time of 1.5 hr without payload. Could anyone recommend any battery types of alternate power sources that I could use?

Comment: In addition to being formally off topic here, this is the type of question you should pursue on a drone forum where there is practical experience of the subject matter.

Comment: 1.5 hours is called C.66 (the rate of drain.) Just about EVERY LiPo these days can handle at least C25 drain rates. So there is NO problem on that aspect. All LiPo will work at your drain rate. The problem is working out what your total mass that must be lifted is and how that is going to be achieved. Once you know that, which includes the current and voltage, you just multiple the mean current by the mean voltage by the 1.5 hours and you get Watt-Hours out of it. That will tell you how much LiPo you need (how many cells and how they are staged up.) You will be using LiPo. That's a given.

Comment: new battery type (graphene)

Comment: best bet http://www.uavfactory.com/page/research-education

Comment: and internal combustion motor may work

Comment: @jonk: Your analysis is flawed. The discharge rate is not the issue here. The key parameter is energy density. It takes a certain amount of power to levitate an object in air, based on its mass. To do that for a certain amount of time requires some amount of energy. If the energy/mass ratio of the battery (based on its technology) doesn't meet this quantity, it can't be done. Most drones using advanced batteries still have flight times under an hour. Increasing the  size of the batteries does not help this at all -- you need better technology, such as liquid fuels (much higher energy density).

Comment: @DaveTweed https://www.wired.com/story/the-physics-of-why-bigger-drones-can-fly-longer/

Comment: @jonk: Exactly! Even if you can reduce the non-battery mass to a negligible fraction of the total, you still run up against the energy density of the battery itself. If you combine the two equations, you get $$P = (\frac{2}{\rho A})^{1/2}(m g)^{3/2}$$ This means that the power (and the energy required for a given hover time) goes up faster than the mass. If you try to compensate with a large, low-velocity impeller, it takes up more of the total mass that you can't devote to battery. You can't win!

Comment: @DaveTweed Increase rotor area.

Comment: @jonk: Did you read my next-to-last sentence?

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes. But I didn't see any calculations. Just a statement.

Answer (score 2):

Most commercial, lipo powered multi-copters top out around 27 minutes.

http://www.dronesglobe.com/guide/long-flight-time/

There are some demos online of flight times as long as 2 hours, but they appear to be extremely minimalist and totally custom builds. Basically just a giant battery, huge props, and a bit of carbon fiber to hold it together.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EF4YeUC2PXA

A fixed wing, aka a plane will easily be able to achieve these kinds of flight times.

RC helicopters may be able to do it. And they give you more power options  (aka combustion engines). But I looked briefly, and the hobby grade gear seems to have similar endurance to multi-copters, so probably not a great option unless you're looking to engineer the whole thing from scratch to maximize flight time.